# Hide image from the table header using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table header as

```
<table class="tablestyle" id="tabHistory">
  <tr>
    <th style="min-width:15%;" onclick="javascript:doSort('0', 'Test Name');"> name</th>
    <th style="min-width:18%;" onclick="javascript:doSort('1', 'platform');">Plat</th>
    <th style="min-width:20%;" onclick="javascript:doSort('2', 'Test Server');"> Server</th>   
    <th style="width:3%;"></th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

code

```
function doSort(index, column) {
  var sortIndex = 'i' + index;
  sortOrder[sortIndex] = (sortOrder[sortIndex] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc";


  var options = {"sortby":column, "order":sortOrder[sortIndex]};
  displayHistory(options, function() {
    var bgImg = (sortOrder[sortIndex] == "asc") ? "./images/asc.gif" : "./images/desc.gif";
    $("#tabHistory th").eq(index).css({
        "background-image": "url(" + bgImg + ")"
    });
  });
}
```

Here in the table head showing images in every header.
I want to show images only in name and server headers not in plat header.
How can i hide the image from the plat header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#tabHistory th").eq(1).css("background-image", "none");
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhVnr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq()` selector:

```
$("#tabHistory th:eq(0),#tabHistory th:eq(2)").css({
    "background-image": "url(" + bgImg + ")"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,  You can also ommit  background-image from Plat th as below:

```
$( "#tabHistory  tr  th:contains('Plat')" ).css( "background-image", "" );
```